# grep pattern recursively in specific directory by file type

Tags: grep

Is this the way to do `grep` recursively by file type on pattern `GUNARS` in directory `gadin-1.0`?

```
grep -rn --include=*.rc "GUNARS" ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/"
```

Comment: "file type" in Unix are things like "regular file", "directory", "socket", "character device", etc. What you seem to ask about is various types of regular files.  At the same time, your example concerns filenames, not file types nor types of regular files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--include=*.rc` is the way to ask the shell for the list of file names in the current directory that start  with `--include=` and end in `.rc` using a shell feature called *globbing*, *filename generation* or *pathname expansion*.

See for instance:

```
zsh% echo --include=*.rc
zsh: no matches found: --include=*.rc
zsh% : > --include=foo.rc > --include=bar.rc
zsh% ls
'--include=bar.rc'  '--include=foo.rc'
zsh% echo --include=*.rc
--include=bar.rc --include=foo.rc
```

Here, you want to pass a literal `--include=*.rc` to `grep`, so:

```
grep -rn '--include=*.rc' GUNARS ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/
```

Or:

```
grep -rn --include='*'.rc GUNARS ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/
```

It's only the `*` that needs to be quoted. The `GUNARS` doesn't need to be quoted as none of those 6 characters are special in the syntax of the shell.

The characters that are special in the syntax of the shell in that code are:

- space that is used here to separate arguments
- `~` which is expanded to the value of the `HOME` environment variable (your home directory) in csh-like and Korn/POSIX-like shells and a few more modern shells at least.
- newline, which delimits that command.

They are the ones that **must not** be quoted. You could quote everything else if you wanted to, except that in several shells including `bash`, a `~` at the start of a word needs to be followed by an *unquoted* `/` or `:` to be expanded¹:

```
'grep' '-rn' '--include=*.rc' 'GUNARS' ~/'Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/'
```

Compare:

```
bash-5.2$ echo ~'/'
~/
```

```
bash-5.2$ echo ~/
/home/me/
```

In Bourne-like shells such as zsh or bash mentioned above, you could use double quotes instead of single quotes, but note that inside double quotes, there are still a few characters that retain their special meaning (`$`, `` ` ``, `\`²).

For `grep`, `-r` and `--include` are non-standard options. Not all `grep` implementations support those and those that do (many for `-r`, few for `--include`) interpret them differently.

A standard and more portable way to report lines containing  `GUNARS` along with the file name and line number in regular files whose name ends in `.rc` in or below the  `$HOME/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/` directory would be:

```
find ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/ -name '*.rc' -type f \
  -exec grep -n GUNARS /dev/null {} +
```

The `/dev/null` it to make sure `grep` is passed at least two files. When passed only one file, it doesn't print its path. Some `grep` implementations have a `-H` option to force the file path to be printed.

With the `zsh` shell, you can also do:

```
grep -n GUNARS /dev/null ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/**/*.rc(.)
```

Where the finding of regular files is done via recursive globbing and glob qualifiers.

That has a few advantages:

- sorts the list of files
- excludes hidden ones (can be added back with the `D` glob qualifier).
- works even for filenames not made of valid text

But also a couple of drawbacks:

- may hit the system's limit of the length of a command if there's a large number of matching files (can be worked around with `zargs`).
- will report an error if there's no matching file.

---

<sup>¹ In csh, where *tilde expansion* is from, `~'/'` would expand to the home directory of the user called `/` (or report a *Unknown user: /.* error).</sup>

<sup>² also beware of characters whose encoding ends in the same encoding as that of `` ` `` or `\` as is the case of several characters in some locales.</sup>

Comment: I often forget the various options for grep.  But I do remember `grep PATTERN [FILES...]`, So I combine `find` and `grep` with in bash: `grep GUNARS $(find ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0 -name *.rc)`

Comment: @Stewart, that's not correct syntax, and not only because you forgot the quotes around `*.rc`. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: I could also do `--include='*.rc'`, right ?

Comment: @Veak, sure, or `--inc'lude=*.r'c`, or `--include=\*.rc` in shells where backslash is also a quoting operator. Anything as long as `*` is quoted.